# Simplifying $\sin\frac{11\pi}{12}\sin\frac{29\pi}{12}-\cos\frac{13\pi}{12}\cos\frac{41\pi}{12}$. Why do I get the wrong answer?

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone explain why I get wrong answer in simplifying this expression?
$$\sin\frac{11\pi}{12}\sin\frac{29\pi}{12}-\cos\frac{13\pi}{12}\cos\frac{41\pi}{12}$$
If we rewrite the expression with new angles,
$$\frac{29\pi}{12}\to\frac{5\pi}{12} \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{13\pi}{12}\to\frac{11\pi}{12}$$ 
we don't change the value of the expression. But, if we now use sine of sum of angles, we get $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $0$.

Why does this happen? Do angles need to be in the same quadrant for the formula to work?

Comment: Sign error: $13\pi/12 \rightarrow -11\pi/12$. Does that fix it?

Comment: Angles do not necessarily need to be in the same quadrant to substitute the angles, but if they are _not_ in the same quadrant you may have a sign change. (But I think not in this case.)

Comment: It is clear that you need to show more of your steps if you expect us to pinpoint which step went wrong. I will point out three things: 1) no, the sum of angles formula does not require any restrictions on quadrants; 2) replacing angles with equivalent angles cannot change the value of any trigonometric expression, so you just made a calculation error somewhere; 3) $13\pi/12$ and $11\pi/12$ are not equivalent angles, but without more context it’s impossible to know whether this error is significant.

Comment: Wait...what about $41\pi/12$? How did you simplify that? (This is most likely the source of your error.)

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you! I didn't change the sign when converting the first angle. Should we delete the question now since it isn't contributing to anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you *don't* get $\frac12$. You get $0$ too, because\begin{align}\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)\cos\left(\frac{41\pi}{12}\right)&=\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)\cos\left(3\pi+\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)\\&=\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right)\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)\\&=\cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}-\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)\\&=\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)\\&=0.\end{align}

Comment: This is ridiculous! I made so many mistakes in such a simple problem! I can't believe. Thank you for the answer.